# Дискорд бот не проигрывает трек

Tags: c#, .net, discord, ffmpeg, youtube

В коде созданы все условия чтобы он мог играть музыку.
Перепробовал все способы/аналоги. Прошу вашей помощи!

```cs
                    try
                    {
                        var tempFileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
                        var getTrackManifest = await Program.youtube.Videos.Streams.GetManifestAsync(Tracks[0].Id);
                        var getAudioStream = getTrackManifest.GetAudioOnlyStreams().TryGetWithHighestBitrate();
                        await Program.youtube.Videos.Streams.DownloadAsync(getAudioStream, $"{tempFileName}");

                        var ffmpegProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                        {
                            FileName = "ffmpeg",
                            Arguments = $"-hide_banner -loglevel panic -i \"{tempFileName}\" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1",
                            UseShellExecute = false,
                            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        });
                        var ffmpegOutput = ffmpegProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
                        using (var audioStream = _audioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Mixed))
                        {
                            if (audioStream == null) { Console.WriteLine("Аудио-поток равен нулю"); }
                            Console.WriteLine("58 str");
                            Console.WriteLine(getAudioStream.Url);
                            try
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Загрузка трека");
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[81920];
                                int bytesRead;
                                while ((bytesRead = await ffmpegOutput.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                                {
                                    await audioStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                }
                                Console.WriteLine($"Трек проигран");
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                await audioStream.FlushAsync();
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("62 str");
                            File.Delete(tempFileName);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
```

Ошибок никаких нет, выводит нужную ссылку на аудио-поток. Но стопорится на строке с  await audioStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
И далее бот просто молчит. Следующий вывод через Console.WriteLine($"Трек проигран"); не происходит.

Comment: Как написано [в документации](https://discordnet.dev/guides/voice/sending-voice.html#transmitting-audio) пробовали?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, так-же всё. Не работает.(Код который я представил выше +- схож с тем что в документации, только он скачивает трек с ютуба и считывает его) ffmpeg полностью рабочий

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сейчас опробовал то, что написано в документации, как итог 0 результатов(бот просто висит в голосовом.)

Comment: Я сейчас полностью скопировал код с документации, закинул нужные библиотеки, указал путь до .mp3 трека, запустил, через пару сек бот начал играть музыку в канал. Скорей всего вы не дожидаетесь обработки `ffmpeg` и думаете, что ничего не происходит. Подождите некое время, должно заиграть.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://ibb.co/tbpQmmN жду уже около получаса. Бот так и не начал играть.

Comment: Ну ок, давайте кидаться скринами. [Вот мой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v37Tg.png), где вы можете увидеть полную копию кода из документации, без единого изменения, а также можете увидеть играющего бота (поверьте, звук идет) в голосовом канале. 5мб файл запустило ~за сек 3, первый раз за сек 10. Дальше будем скринами кидаться, доказывать что каждый не прав, или всеж будете искать причину у себя, что именно вы не так сделали? Повторю - полная копия кода из документации...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот код - https://pastebin.com/DuMyjN0c . Не понимаю в чём ошибка! Всё ровно так-же как у вас процесс ffmpeg создаётся с нужными параметрами, но бот молчит как рыба.

Comment: Ну.. Я не знаю. Попробуйте своему боту выдать все права, как на сайте (раздел [Bot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkApe.png)), так и клиенту (`var config = new DiscordSocketConfig { GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All }; new DiscordSocketClient(config);`). Код... У меня лично в примере выше не стоит, все работает. Ну а галки на сайте, они больше для событий, которые получает бот, не думаю, что будут работать на аудио... Ради любопытства, сделайте чистый проект, в него добавьте клиент, коннект, и по событию `Ready` выполнения кода из документации. Если сработает - у вас проекте что-то не то.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, сейчас попробую сделать как вы говорите

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот, что получилось у меня - https://ibb.co/5kTKPZv .  Результатов опять же 0, бот просто присоеденяется к голосовому и сидит молча, в конфиге стоит GatewayIntents = GatewayIntents.All,

Comment: P.S Сейчас поменял версию с .NET 6.0 на .Net Framework 4.8.1. Тоже самое.

Comment: Я понял вашу проблему, вы накосячили с библиотеками (.dll), которые требуются. Внимательно прочитайте документацию, и посмотрите что там нужно. `Audio requires two native libraries, libsodium and opus. Both of these libraries must be placed in the runtime directory of your bot`. Я удалил у себя `libsodium` и получил тот-же результат, что и у вас, бот зашел, а дальше тишина, без ошибок. На всякий случай собрал вам простой [пример](https://evgeniy-z.ru/DiscordBot.zip), со всеми библиотеками, и даже треком, достаточно открыть в студии, указать нужные id, запустить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Огромно спасибо @EvgeniyZ , который подсказал правильное решение!
**Вся ошибка была из-за того что я скачал одну библиотеку**

*Нужно скачать две библиотеки: 

**Opus 

libsodium*** 
Все они приложены к официальной документации: [github](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/tree/dev/voice-natives)